# What is the difference between system variables and user variables is Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to learn about variables in Azure data factory. What is the difference between user variables and system variables?

Sincerely
Chris

Answer (score 1):

**System Variables**
Predefined by Azure Data Factory, they provide system-related info for pipeline runs, like IDs, timestamps, and trigger data. They're read-only and for dynamic control flow.

**User Variables**
User-defined variables holding custom values. They're mutable, letting users store reusable data (like paths or settings) across activities or pipelines.